# How to implement Amazon Pay javascript in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to port the following JS to typescript

```
// your head section here
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onAmazonLoginReady = function() {
    amazon.Login.setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
  };
</script>
```

In particular, I am confused how to bind a function to the "window" object.

I get the following error:

> [ts] Property 'onAmazonLoginReady' does not exist on type 'Window'.

I am using typescript with react.

Comment: You will have to do something like `declare const window: any` in the file where you access window. Using `window['onAmazonLoginReady']` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-payments

You can also view it on Github to implement the code by yourself.